# problem with subordinate subjects within a data table

Tags: mysql, data-integrity

I'm creating a database for a small training organisation and trying to resolve a problem with the following table

Trainees

Trainees ID , Trainees First, Trainees Last, Order Name (optional), Trainees Email,
   Trainees HomeTel, Trainees Mob, Trainees StrAddress, Trainees City,
   Trainees PostCode, HP, Mod Training, Mailing list

The field HP stand for Health Professionals and I need to distinguish the group within the table. They also have the option to do either a modular training, or normal.
Should I create a subset table in this case, or is there another solution?

Another issue is related to Mailing list. I need to flag whether they want to be on subscribers list. Is it ok to have the field repeated in other tables such as customers. I'm not sure this will be good for data integrity.

Any help will be much appreciated,
Zan

Comment: if you have a table Trainess, your fields should be `ID`, `FirstName`, `LastName` instead of *Trainees ID , Trainees First, Trainees Last* same for the others.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question **Should I create a subset table in this case, or is there another solution?** you shouldn’t create it, with the columns that you have you can add or remove more details to obtain the result that you’re searching for.

For the second question **Is it ok to have the field repeated in other tables such as customers?** It is ok, that is good for the data integrity and it could help to apply statments like **select, join and others** but you should view if it really necessary to obtain what you’re looking for.